# Dynamically creating python class from a protobuf file at run time?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

In Python, is it possible *at run time* to convert a Google Protocol Buffers `.proto` file into a python class that reads that data? Python is a very dynamic language. When you use `protoc` to convert a `.proto` file to python source code, the generated code makes a lot of use of python metaclasses, so it's already very dynamic.

Ideally, I'm thinking of something like this:

```
import whatever
module = whatever.load_from_file("myfile.proto")
```

Is this possible?

*(I am new to protocol buffers, please let me know if my question makes no sense)*

Comment: what is in `proto` file class definition ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Perhaps my question was unclear, I have updated it. I'm talking about Google's Protocol Buffers format

Comment: If the `.proto` file itself is a python source code that you want to include as a module, you are probably looking for this: `import imp;   module = imp.load_source('any_name', 'myfile.proto')`

Comment: Anyway, just import the converted python code (perhaps use `sys.path.append(its_dir)` before).

Comment: @Berci the `.proto` file is not python source code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In theory, all the pieces exist to make this work. The Python protobuf implementation could call the C++ `.proto` parser library (`libprotoc`) as a C extension to get Descriptors, and then could feed those into the metaclasses.

However, as far as I know, no one has quite tied it altogether. (Disclaimer: My knowledge is a few years old, I may have missed a new development, but I don't see anything in the docs.)

Incidentally, [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org)'s Python implementation does do what you describe, proving it is possible. But that doesn't help you if you need to work with Protobuf format.

(Disclosure: I was the author of most of Google's open source Protobuf code, and I am also the author of Cap'n Proto.)

Comment: Alas, I need to work with protobuf files. I'm not in a position to change that. However "No, I don't think anyone has done this" is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution to this problem is to use **init**.py. See: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

You can invoke your script to generate Python protobuf classes in **init**.py. Upon importing, that script will be automatically invoked to generate Python protobuf classes.